# Unity Button Change Color In Script Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to change the color of a button in a script but for some reason, my code cannot see the 'colors' element of a button. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string selectedList;
    Transform[] t;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        t=GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Button button = t[PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedList)].GetComponent<Button>();

        ColorBlock colorBlock = button.colors;
        colorBlock.normalColor = new Color32(191, 255, 203, 255);
        button.colors = colorBlock;
    }
}
```

When this is run, I get the following error:

```
error CS1061: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'colors' and no accessible extension method 'colors' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why could this be? I have tried importing as UnityEngine.UI.Button, I have tried using different elements that I've read people use but nothing is seeming to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use a Button reference? Also, why are you hardcoding an array index? And why in PlayerPrefs? Array indexes are not guaranteed to be identical on every load. Furthermore, why are you using Update() to change the color? Why do you import the System.Collections package when you don't actually use it? There are many red flags in your code that just scream of bad design. What are you trying to achieve? Buttons have included functionalities to change properties on actions and Unity provides events to change even more options not included in default options. What is the actual use case?

Comment: @Tom Jedi I've test your code (basically the last 3 lines) with my button, it changes color on play and works fine. I don't know why this error happend. The colors property is belong to the Selectable type, and Button is its inheritance. What version of Unity do you use? By the way, if you want to set the normal color of the button from script, don't set it in Update(), set in Start() instead, for optimization.

Comment: I use Unity 2021.3.5f. There is 100% a better way to do what I'm doing, I basically want buttons to stay a new colour when clicked, like they do when selected, but not to go back to their original colour when another button is clicked. Setting the button's normal colour was the only solution I could think of. As for the hardcoded index, that is because what is selected is determined from PlayerPrefs